# C++ minimal threadsafe array based on std::deque

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, thread-safety, lock-free

Here is a minimal example of a threadsafe array I want to build on for a timeseries application, with the following characteristics:

- Ever-growing, and the already contained elements remain constant
- (Usually) a single writer calling `push_back`
- Multiple dependent readers

Here is the corresponding implementation, or rather an early attempt of it:

```
template<typename T>
struct threadsafe_array
{
    auto operator[](int i) const
    {
        return deq[i];
    }

    auto size() const
    {
        return deq_size.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    }

    void push_back(T const& t)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mut);
        deq.push_back(t);
        lock.unlock();
        deq_size.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
    }

private:
    std::deque<T> deq;
    std::atomic<int> deq_size{0};
    std::mutex mut;
};
```

My underlying ideas:

1. reads of the available elements through `operator[](int)` are carried out lock-free.
2. a `std::deque` is used as the underlying container because it does not invalidate concurrent reads when doing a push-back (--in contrast, a `std::vector` could as it potentially does a reallocation)
3. the `push_back` is forwarded to the underlying deque, on which it is applied in an atomic way through locking the `std::mutex`. Thereafter, the variable `deq_size` of type `std::atomic<int>` variable is adjusted using release semantics (so that the previous `push_back` is not reordered after the `fetch_add`).
4. if there are reads occurring in between adding an element to the deque and the adjustment of the size, they have have to get along with a smaller `size()`, i.e. as if the array had not been updated. Calling `operator[size()]` therefore does not need to be undefined behvaiour as it is for `std::deque` (but that's more an inconsistency than a feature).

Questions:

- Is this thing already threadsafe and doing what I wrote, or am I missing some points?
- Are the memory orders in the atomic operations ok, or are there better choices (e.g. `memory_order_relaxed` for the load in `size()`)?
- Is it preferable doing the update of the size in `push_back()` under the lock (and thus, if I see it right, limit the size difference between `size()` and the underlying `std::deque::size()` to only one)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code isn't thread-safe, as executing a read with `.operator[]()` and a write with `.push_back()` isn't synchronized in any way.
Even though no references to elements are invalidated by `std::deque<T>::push_back()`, it can change the data-structure to retrieve those references.

What you want to look into is called a readers-writer-lock, which is the primitive for allowing either multiple readers or only a single writer access at the same time.
C++17 provides it as [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex), so you might have to use [`boost::shared_mutex`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) unless your library is already there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know the reader-writer lock and decided against ... in fact, the whole idea of this question is a lock-free read. So again, why is it not thread-safe? A call to `push_back` adds an element to the deque, but leaves (references to) the rest untouched. Reading any element except the one just about to push_back is imo safe, you agree?

Comment: Now to the last element: a reader thread is allowed to read it only after it really exists, as is indicated by the `size()` variable which changes only after the push_back is finished. Reading elements outer the size is undefined behavior, as it's for a normal single-threaded vector. So when one accepts this by definition, where is the code non-threadsafe?

Comment: Yes, it leaves references to the rest untouched. That doesn't mean it leaves the datastructure to **get that reference** untouched.

Comment: Subtle point, but I got it. Although I can't think of a mechanism that would invalidate`operator[]`, it's not guaranteed by the standard that it really does. An that kills it... I'll mark your answer as accepted on behalf of your comment.

Answer (score 3):

On a scale of 1 to 100, how confident are you in your ability to use `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` correctly?

---

The common implementation of `std::deque` as a double-ended array of pointers to arrays will definitely hit the bug that Deduplicator describes, whenever the deque reallocates its array-of-pointers.

Here's a reproducer for libc++'s `deque`, which reallocates on the 1024th call to `push_back`:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/3nyt9fGZAiS9yScK

Reproducing on libstdc++ is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

You should always use `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` whenever you're manipulating mutex locks. Your manual mutex-fiddling here will cause a deadlock whenever `T`'s copy-constructor throws.

---

Consider providing `push_back(T&&)` and possibly a template `emplace_back(Args&&...)` in addition to your `push_back(const T&)`. Of course this just increases the surface area exposed to the deadlock bug above; so start using `lock_guard` *first* and add these member functions *afterward*.

---

*Now*, on a scale of 1 to 100, how confident are you in your ability to use `memory_order_acquire` and `memory_order_release` correctly? (For comparison, I rate myself at about a 15... and I'm able to spot bugs like the above fairly easily. Given that you didn't spot those bugs, *should* you be using memory orders other than `seq_cst`? Why or why not?)

Comment: Seems then that I'm a five, and there's lots to learn ahead, so thanks for your comments. (i) the deque-access error is there from the principles, and it's also good to see it in action. Probably a stable, non-contigouos `T**` is more appropriate here. (ii) I didn't want to focus on the copy-constructor, so I'd have it better `delete`d, but as it is it's implicitly there and thus surely a bug, so thanks for pointing.

Comment: (iii) With respect to the memory order: as far I know `std::memory_order_seq_cst` does not prevent the reordering of non-atomic accesses to after the respective position, and I wanted the previous `push_back` happen first ... this is why I chose `std::memory_order_release`. The `std::memory_order_acquire` then came in rather intuitively (this is why I asked whether it's correct). The main question was, whether the update strategy is resp. can be made correct, i.e. lock only the write accesses (which are always push_backs) and don't lock the read accesses unlocked. What do you mean?

Comment: (i) Nothing wrong with a `deque` as long as you take the mutex lock at the right times. I think you'll find the same problems cropping up with raw `T**`, although I admit I'm not sure exactly what you're thinking of. (ii) `threadsafe_array`'s copy and move ops are implicitly deleted because `threadsafe_array` has non-moveable members (the `atomic` and the `mutex`).

Comment: (iii) My *only* point re memory-orders is that you'll probably get them wrong even if you think hard about them — and *certainly* if you go by "intuition"! Prefer the safety of `seq_cst`, especially on x86 where the different memory-orders give identical codegen anyway. Ask yourself: is it worth the extra keystrokes, if *all* you're doing is introducing bugs for ARM users? :)